# Where will we get code of java native function

Tags: java

we have a class called Runtime in java. It uses native functions to give free memory , total memory and available processors. Where can we find the source code of this native functions and also locations of native files.

Comment: Which JVM implementation are you using?

Comment: I konw a little of it.But I can only explain it in Chinese.Sorry.My English is pool.Hopes someone answer~

Comment: use http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en| translator

Answer (score 2):

Google code search for "file:Runtime.c openjdk" gives [this file](http://www.google.com/codesearch#wltrSXuOaoI/src/share/native/java/lang/Runtime.c&q=file:Runtime.c%20openjdk&type=cs) which looks it contains the JNI code for Runtime.java.